# NSUrlSessionDownloadDelegate - DidFinishDownloading checking for "File Not Found"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have setup a background downloader on my app for iOS. The only problem I am having is checking if the file exists server side (as it is possible that it may not).

```
public override void DidFinishDownloading(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDownloadTask downloadTask, NSUrl location)
```

This is always returning even if there is no file to grab but then will save the tmp file as if it has downloaded successfully. Like so.

```
// Create the filename
var documentsFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
NSUrl destinationURL = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(documentsFolderPath, destFile));

// Remove any existing file in our destination
NSError error;
fileManager.Remove(destinationURL, out error);
bool success = fileManager.Copy(sourceFile, documentsFolderPath + "/" + destFile, out error);
if (!success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error during the copy: {0}", error.LocalizedDescription);
}
```

Now how can I check the response status from here? As I am downloading in the background I cannot use a completion block and that is the only place I can find where I can possibly get the response status.

The only other way I can see to handle this is to "ping" the file before I setup a task to check it is there, is this correct or can I just allow this download delegate to handle it?

Comment: what does the return information look like if there is no file on server ?

Comment: @ColeXia I don't know how to even find that information from this delegate. Thats kinda the question, if i had any information like that I could work it but but it seems to just "think" it downloaded the file and saves out the `.tmp` file.

Comment: @Ruddy, You can get the sever response in the `DidFinishDownloading` delegate via `downloadTask.Response`